# accepting value in edittext even if it has spaces

Tags: android

i have this code in my app. which accepts the value of the edittext

```
        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("bag")) {

                btnEnter.setEnabled(false);
            int a=Integer.parseInt(textView2.getText().toString());
            int b=a+10;
            String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
            textView2.setText(s1);  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

my problem is if the user puts a single space in the edittext then proceeds with the "bag" it still prompts wrong like this for example

" " = space

" " bag ----- wrong
bag ----- correct

how can i set that with space it can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      String ans2 = ans.trim();
      if (ans2.equalsIgnoreCase("bag")) {

        btnEnter.setEnabled(false);
        int a=Integer.parseInt(textView2.getText().toString());
        int b=a+10;
        String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
        textView2.setText(s1);  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[trim() function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace
>   omitted.

Since @ρяσѕρєя K deleted his answer before I got back to delete mine I will add his simplified edit. Change

```
if (ans2.equalsIgnoreCase("bag")) {
```

to

```
if (ans.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("bag")) {
```

then no need for

```
String ans2 = ans.trim();
```

But using a second variable may be better for readibility or functionality in certain situations

**Edit**
To take care of in between spaces you might try

```
if (!ans.contains("") && ans.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("bag")) {
```

Not sure why that doesn't work but you can use the `replace` function for `Strings`

```
       String ans2 = ans.replace(" ", "");
       if (ans2.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("bag")) {
```

Comment: Why you repeat the same answer.

Comment: @TGMCians I didn't mean to. I was in the middle of posting when he answered. I got distracted and didn't see the other answer. Not trying to steal any glory

Comment: Yes there is. I said I got distracted and wasn't paying attention to the other answer. I will delete. No need to get upset.

Comment: I am not getting upset. Its ok now @ρяσѕρєя K has deleted his answer now. So now no repetition.

Comment: @TGMCians ok, sorry about the confusion. I was going to delete after I saw that they were the same answer. I started typing mine before the other was posted. Just got distracted and didn't post right away

Comment: Its ok now. Don't get panic. We are friends keep its up.

Comment: @TGMCians ok, I'm glad we can still be friends after all of this. You know how rowdy the SO can get :)

Comment: Thanks @codeMagic it works the way i want now i can continue with my app

Comment: btw my friend told me this. what if i do this B" " A " " G. the spaces between letters still prompts wrong

Comment: but i think putting spaces in the between the letters is already an error. i guess i`ll let it that way thanks again btw @codeMagic

Comment: You're welcome! Edited one more time. Replace should work for that, as well. Give it a try

Comment: It's what the SO community is about. Help others when you can and be respectful and we will be even